# PHP PDO Result Stuck in Memory

Tags: php, pdo

I can't seem to get PHP to release the memory it uses fetching mysql result sets using PDO, without exiting the script completely. This is a problem in scripts with large datasets that then need to run for a while and do things after the results are fetched. I've tried setting the variables all to null and unsetting them, but no matter what the size of the mysql result stays in memory until the script ends. Here's a simplified example:

```
<?php

gc_enable();

echo 'Memory usage at start: ' . round(memory_get_usage(true) / (1024 * 1024), 3) . ' MB' . "\n";

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
    PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
];
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

echo 'Memory usage before query: ' . round(memory_get_usage(true) / (1024 * 1024), 3) . ' MB' . "\n";

$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `SOME_LARGE_TABLE`;') or die(dbErrorHandler($pdo, $stmt, __FILE__, __LINE__));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$stmt = null;
$results = null;
$pdo = null;
unset($stmt);
unset($results);
unset($pdo);

gc_collect_cycles();
echo 'Memory usage at end: ' . round(memory_get_usage(true) / (1024 * 1024), 3) . ' MB' . "\n";
sleep(100000);
```

For the example I stripped out the real query and DB parameters, but the actual script outputs this:

```
Memory usage at start: 10 MB
Memory usage before query: 10 MB
Memory usage at end: 32 MB
```

I am using PHP 8.0.10 on Ubuntu with mySQL 5.7.

Comment: What you want is `memory_get_usage(false)`. `memory_get_usage(true)` returns the "total" memory allocated to the PHP process not the "currently" used by it.

Comment: If the PHP memory is a concern then maybe you should consider unbuffered queries `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY`

Comment: What do you mean "without exiting the script"? The whole point of a PHP script is to get invoked, start up, get all the data it needs to form a response, then form that resonse _and then die again_. Under no circumstances should it be hanging around long enough for memory accumulation to ever become a problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I mean I want to be able to fetch the result set from mySQL, use it, unset it, then have the script do other things without the result set being stuck eating up memory.

Comment: @Rain If I change memory_get_usage(true) to memory_get_usage(false) I don't get the accurate number of how much memory occupied on the server, I get what's occupied by this script, but it's still "holding" the memory used in memory_get_usage(true). The problem I am trying to solve is multiple scripts that need large datasets running concurrently and maxing out the servers memory, because they are holding the mySQL dataset in memory even though it's not being used anymore and is unset.

Comment: Why would it take up _that_ much memory though? How much data are you asking for? Because if it's so much data that PHP's running out of memory, that's a clear case of trying to make PHP do something that SQL should probably be doing instead.